# How to show complete log messages on Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

Most of the messages I looked at in the history are about disabling certain aspects of the log. I'd like the opposite. I'm seeing lots of messages like:

> " DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.traceDebug (91) - Writing ["
> <rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2. (truncated)...]"

I'd like to see the entire, non-truncated, (in this case) RSS feed. Any idea how I can persuade Spring/Logback/console/maven to do this?

Bonus question -- how would I write a test to verify that the logs are actually not truncated? I don't have them persisted in any way, just on the console. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With DEBUG log level, Spring only logs the truncated data. With TRACE log level, Spring logs the complete data.

You could configure something like

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor = TRACE
```

To test the output written to the log (like `System.out`), have a look into [OutputCapture](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-output-capture-test-utility).

```java
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
class OutputCaptureTests {

    @Test
    void testName(CapturedOutput output) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        assertThat(output).contains("World");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also set the TRACE logging level on the HttpLogging entity like this:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.HttpLogging = TRACE
```